# Kafka-confluent: How to use pk.mode=record_key for upsert and delete mode in JDBC sink connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

In Kafka confluent, how can we use upsert using the source as CSV file while using `pk.mode=record_key` for composite key in the MySQL table? The upsert mode is working while using the `pk.mode=record_values`. Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done?

I am getting this error if I am trying with `pk.mode=record_key`. Error - Caused by: `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException`: Need exactly one PK column defined since the key schema for records is a primitive type.
Below is my JDBC sink connector configuration:

```
    {
    "name": "<name>",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "<topic name>",
    "connection.url": "<url>",
    "connection.user": "<user name>",
    "connection.password": "*******",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "batch.size": "50000",
    "table.name.format": "<table name>",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "field1,field2",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "max.retries": "10",
    "retry.backoff.ms": "3000",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `pk.mode` of `record.value`.
This means take field(s) from the *value* of the message and use them as the primary key in the target table and for `UPSERT` purposes.

If you set `record.key` it will try to take the key field(s) from the Kafka message *key*. Unless you've actually got the values in your message key, this is not the setting that you want to use.

These might help you further:

- [Kafka Connect JDBC Sink deep-dive: Working with Primary Keys](https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/)
- https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video
- https://rmoff.dev/ksqldb-jdbc-sink-video

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to upsert. I tried with a list of fields to in `pk.fields` since my MySQL table has a composite key and it worked. But if I am enabling delete mode too in the connector, then I have to set `pk.mode` as `record_key`. Here I am not able to set a composite key. I tried doing that using `partition by` while creating streams. It added a new row into the table and did not use the individual fields of the table as primary keys. I will refer to the link and try it once again.

Comment: Your comment describes a different problem from that which you put in your original question :) Can you edit your original question and make it clear example what the issue is that you're having please?

Comment: I have posted another question regarding the issue mentioned in the comments. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61087098/kafka-confluent-delete-mode-in-jdbc-sink-connector-is-giving-error-and-not-able)

Comment: When `delete_enabled=true` and `pk.mode=record_value` you get an Error: `org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Primary key mode must be 'record_key' when delete support is enabled`.

Comment: @felicienb check out https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/