# Kafka Confluent: delete mode in JDBC sink connector is giving error and not able to use composite key in `pk.fields`

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am having two issues.

1) I enabled the `delete.enabled` as `true`. But since it needs the `pk.mode` to be set as `record_key` I am not able to use the composite key of my MySQL table as I could use when I set `pk.mode` as `record_value`. I tried to add a composite key in the Stream while converting the records into AVRO format using the `partition by` option. But it added a new column in the MySQL table. The row is not set if I am using a single primary key instead of a composite key.

2) The delete mode is not working in my sink connector. I used `insert.mode` as `upsert`. My MySQL table contains fields that have a `not null` attribute. The error that is thrown: `Col has a not-null attribute. It cannot be null`. For delete, I am removing all values in the record except for the primary key value. Example of a tombstone record for delete operation - `,,,,,,,,<primary key value>,,,,,,,,,`. If I am adding the values for all those columns that have the attribute as `not-null`, the update operation gets executed. Also, I want to know if I am making any mistake while creating a tombstone record.

Comment: Hi @Sanjay, Did you solved this issue. I am stuck in this issue since long. If you figured out anything regarding this, please do share here.
Thanks